# Activity faild when rotating several times in monodroid

Tags: android, rotation, xamarin.android

In my monodroid application I have an activity that users may roatate it.
when several time back to back i rotate it it cause this error:

```
 12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115): Activity myapp.myActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405bc398 that was originally added here
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity myapp.myActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405bc398 that was originally added here
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:275)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:430)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at myapp.myActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at myapp.myActivity.onCreate(PropertyShowActivity.java:77)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1037)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-17 11:58:40.367: E/WindowManager(2115):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 11:58:40.377: W/MapActivity(2115): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@40626398
```

i dont know for what is this.
can any body help me?

I have also this info before the above errors:

```
Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@40626398
```

Recycling map object.
Clamp target GC heap from 33.796MB to 32.000MB
395280-byte external allocation too large for this process.
VM won't let us allocate 395280 bytes
Clamp target GC heap from 33.789MB to 32.000MB

i have some images in my activity that loads with Universal Image Loader
is it because of them?
if its true how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not changing the layout or needing to reconfigure/reload controls or your layout, you might want to look into adding an attribute change like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Icon = "@drawable/MyActivity", Theme = "@style/AppTheme"
                , ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

The **Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation** property notifies the activity that any orientation changes will need to be handled manually. So, if you just want the view to rotate without restarting your activity, making that attribute change should solve your problem.

If you will be needing to change your layout or need to take actions on the orientation change, you will want to override the **OnConfigurationChanged** method.

More information on this process can be found at the [Xamarin Docs Site](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Handling_Rotation). Look at the Section *"Preventing Activity Restart"*.

Answer (score 0):

It is posible, that you created memory leak somewhere. Check if you are not storing references to Gui objects.

Comment: surely i didn't it.because i don't know how should to do storing references to gui.can you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you create a Dialog (or a class derived from Dialog) in your OnCreate() method. The Dialog uses an internal class PhoneWindow that leaks. When rotating the device, the activity runs through the lifecycle, and there you should clean up your dialog. The suggested place is the OnPause() method:

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
   base.OnPause();

   if (this.dlg != null)
      this.dlg.Dismiss();
}
```

The Activity lifecycle is described here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: i use monodroid and my activity class have not any attribute by 'dlg' name.and have not also any thing like dialog.what should i use for this porpose?

Comment: i think it is not about this.i have an other activity that also have image gallery and show their images by universal image loader and have not any dialogs. in this activity i have this problem also.can any body say me hwo can store references to gui based on 'snapix' answer?

Comment: Without showing more code we can only guess. Maybe you should provide a minimal code example where the error still shows. I got the exact stack trace when I had the problem and I solved it as I described.